# Fluent NHibernate from appSettings

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to configure my NHibernate Fluent from an app.config and an appSettingKey.

Is there someone who can explain how should the file app.config look like?

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005  
   .ConnectionString(c => c  
    .FromAppSetting("appSettingKey"));
```

And this is my connectionsString

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=True
```

This doesn't work:

```
<appSettingKey>"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ABC;Integrated Security=True"</appSettingKey>
```

// Mats, Stockholm, Sweden

Comment: I think Erik has your answer. Did you mean to ask as well why your connection string does not work? You might want to try "Integrated security=SSPI"

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to configure Fluent NHibernate as in your example and use a connection string from App.config. Below is an example of how I would accomplish that.

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="FluentNHibernateConnection"
      value="server=.;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Integrated Security=True" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code to create a session factory:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var fluentConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
        .ConnectionString.FromAppSetting("FluentNHibernateConnection");

    PersistenceModel persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel();
    persistenceModel.addMappingsFromAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly);

    Configuration nhConfig = new Configuration()
        .AddProperties(fluentConfig.ToProperties());

    persistenceModel.Configure(nhConfig);

    return nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

Hope it helps.

/Erik (a fellow "Stockholmare")

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of [Database Configuration](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Database-configuration) in the [Fluent NHibernate wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                                c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connectStringKey)
                            )//End ConnectionString
                        )//End Database
                .Mappings(m =>m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ADomainClassType>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

This is how I build my session factory.